# Throw an IllegalStateException when calling start() method of MediaRecorder - Android

Tags: android, exception, illegalstateexception, android-mediarecorder

I know that this question has asked several times. But still I couldn't find the reason for this; none of them helped to solve this issue.

I'm trying to record an audio clip using android MediaRecorder and want to play it. But I'm getting IllegalStateException at following line of code.

```
recorder.start();
```

This is my code:

```
private void startRecording() {
    try {

        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audio_recording.3gp";

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        // recorder.setOutputFile(fos.getFD()); 
        recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in preparing recorder!!! IllegelStateException");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in preparing recorder!!!");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException caught during recording!!! IO Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Error log:

```
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3103)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3098)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    ... 11 more
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:146)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.MainActivity.onRecord(MainActivity.java:94)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    at com.example.audiorecordtest.MainActivity.onSayButtonClick(MainActivity.java:66)
02-17 19:09:40.086: E/AndroidRuntime(25620):    ... 14 more
```

I have declared required permissions also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: illegalStateEception could be a thread-issue.
Maybe you need a Monitor (synchronized)

Comment: None of tutorials say that we need a Monitor. :-(

Comment: can you post the tutorial url?

Comment: [http://talkingtechnologies.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-audio-recording-and-playback.html] and [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html]

Comment: where do you start startRecording() ?

Comment: in the main thread, as follwing.

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
  if (start) {
   startRecording();
  } else {
   stopRecording();
  }
 }

Comment: looks very strange: "prepare :: IllegalStateException if it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat()." "play:: IllegalStateException if it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat(). " 


does your program compile and is published on the phone at all??

Comment: Yes.My program was compiled and published on the phone at all.this exception comes when I click on "Start recording" Button. :-(

Comment: what throws the exceptio, start() or prepare()? ?

Comment: Start(). I mentioned it in the problem title as well. :-(

Comment: oops.. ok
but as the docu says:
start throws the exception **only** if it is called before prepare().
So, this looks very strange

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24667/discussion-between-ciph3r-and-s-basnagoda)